# Cordova: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'

Tags: ajax, cordova, cross-domain, getjson, whitelist

I am trying to bring back my Cordova App, since the last time it was working my server expired and I had to rebuild the database and load my php interfaces, on a different domain than it used to be hosted.

So after all the work on the server was done and everything is like it was, I changed all links in my app and the permissions to external sources but still when I run the app, when it encounters the first getJSON call it gives the following error on the javascript console:

**Failed to load resource** jquery-3.2.1.js (9566,10)

On the output stream it says:

E chromium: [ERROR:sync_resource_handler.cc(63)] Cross origin redirect denied

I added the following error function to get a better idea of the error:

```
console.log(xhr.status + status + error);
```

and got this on the console:

0errorNetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://www.squirreldevelopment.it/notebet/request_utilities.php'.

I have whitelist plugin installed and the following in my config.xml :

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.3" />
<allow-navigation href="https://squirreldevelopment.it/notebet/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://squirreldevelopment.it/notebet/*" />
<access origin="https://squirreldevelopment.it/notebet/*" />
```

I also tried with href="*" with no success.

In the html head i have

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src 'self' https://www.squirreldevelopment.it/notebet/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

At the top of the php file i have:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
```

I checked the generated manifest and there is the permission for internet access

I did try to reinstall the whitelist plugin with no success.

this is my original piece of code that does the call:

```
        $.getJSON('https://www.squirreldevelopment.it/notebet/request_request_utilities.php', function (result) {
        console.log("success");
        $.each(result, function (i, field) {
            console.log("reading request_utilities.php");
            status = field.status;
            val_aggiorna = field.aggiorna;
            console.log("ended reading request_utilities.php");
            statusResult = result;
        });
        if (status == 0) {
            errore('Error loading data');
        } else {
            console.log("status ok");
            console.log("requestData");
            requestData(urls);
        }
    });
```

This is the code I am using now to debug (they get the same error):

```
        $.ajax({
        crossDomain:true,
        dataType: "json",
        url: "https://www.squirreldevelopment.it/notebet/request_utilities.php",
        success: function (result) {
                    console.log("success");
                    $.each(result, function (i, field) {
                        console.log("reading request_utilities.php");
                        status = field.status;
                        val_aggiorna = field.aggiorna;
                        console.log("ended reading request_utilities.php");
                        statusResult = result;
                    });
                    if (status == 0) {
                        errore('Error loading data');
                    } else {
                        console.log("status ok");
                        console.log("requestData");
                        requestData(urls);
                    }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(xhr.status + status + error);
              }
    });
```

I have no more clues on how to fix this. 
Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: I forgot to say I set async: false

Answer (score 1):

Please try the CSP like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="
                default-src 'self' data: gap:; 
                connect-src 'self' https://www.squirreldevelopment.it;
                script-src 'self' data: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
                style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
                media-src *; 
                ">
```

I would start with config.xml setup like:

```
 <access allows-arbitrary-loads-for-media="true" allows-arbitrary-loads-in-web-content="true" allows-local-networking="true" origin="*"/>
 <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
 <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
 <allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

If you make it work narrow access according to your need.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work . The fact that it worked before I migrated to a new server makes me think there could be something I forgot to check/fix but I've googled for everything related to problems with cross requests and I've found nothing I haven't tried